# There is how to change url domain on some posts?

Tags: multisite, pages, url-rewriting, urls, site-url

There is how to change the URL on some posts? 
Like, for example, my website is www.mydomain.com, on posts it's like www.mydomain.com/post

now can i change some posts to a url like www.myotherdomain.com?

or i need to make another wordpress website and post directly there this separate posts?

Comment: I read this a couple times and I'm not sure what your asking.  Can you change your domain name?  Import your posts to another site?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis i'm not fluent in english so i don't know exactly how to say it. 

it's like, on my primary domain i make posts normally, but i want to make some posts shows my other secondary domain, but still on the main site

idk if this are really possible, it's something that i'm trying to make

Comment: Yeah, you could use the RSS feed, google Wordpress Auto Post or RSS, I'm sure there are plugins

Comment: Thanks, i will search about the plugins and try to put on my website :D